# classmethod for Tkinter-Monitor-Window

Tags: python, tkinter, class-method

I would like to realise a monitor window that reports the user about ongoing computations. To do so I wrote a little class. But as I would like to use it accross different modules in an easy fashion I thought to implement it with classmethods. This allows to use it in the following way without instances:

```
from MonitorModule import Monitor
Monitor.write("xyz")
```

Also, if I use it in an other module, the output of **Monitor.write()** within **other_module.py** will be displayed in the same window.

This I can import in each module to redirect specific outputs to the same monitor. I got it to work except one little thing that I don't understand. I can't close the Monitor-window with the specific handler that I wrote. I could do it with the non-classmethod-way but not with the handler as a classmethod.

Look at the code:

```
import Tkinter
class Monitor_non_classmothod_way(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.mw = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.mw.title("Messages by NeuronSimulation")
    self.text = Tkinter.Text(self.mw, width = 80, height = 30)
    self.text.pack()
    self.mw.protocol(name="WM_DELETE_WINDOW", func=self.handler)
    self.is_mw = True
  def write(self, s):
    if self.is_mw:
      self.text.insert(Tkinter.END, str(s) + "\n")
    else:
      print str(s)
  def handler(self):
    self.is_mw = False
    self.mw.quit()
    self.mw.destroy()

class Monitor(object):
  @classmethod
  def write(cls, s):
    if cls.is_mw:
      cls.text.insert(Tkinter.END, str(s) + "\n")
    else:
      print str(s)
  @classmethod
  def handler(cls):
    cls.is_mw = False
    cls.mw.quit()
    cls.mw.destroy()
  mw = Tkinter.Tk()
  mw.title("Messages by NeuronSimulation")
  text = Tkinter.Text(mw, width = 80, height = 30)
  text.pack()
  mw.protocol(name="WM_DELETE_WINDOW", func=handler)
  close = handler
  is_mw = True

a = Monitor_non_classmothod_way()
a.write("Hello Monitor one!")
# click the close button: it works
b = Monitor()
Monitor.write("Hello Monitor two!")
# click the close button: it DOESN'T work, BUT:
# >>> Monitor.close()
# works...
```

So, the classmethod seems to work and also seems to be accessible in the right way! Any idea, what went wrong, that it doesn't work with the button?

Cheers, Philipp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need lots of classmethods just to make it easy to use an object across multiple modules.

Instead consider making an instance at module import time as shown here:

```
import Tkinter

class Monitor(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.mw = Tkinter.Tk()
    self.mw.title("Messages by NeuronSimulation")
    self.text = Tkinter.Text(self.mw, width = 80, height = 30)
    self.text.pack()
    self.mw.protocol(name="WM_DELETE_WINDOW", func=self.handler)
    self.is_mw = True

  def write(self, s):
    if self.is_mw:
      self.text.insert(Tkinter.END, str(s) + "\n")
    else:
      print str(s)

  def handler(self):
    self.is_mw = False
    self.mw.quit()
    self.mw.destroy()

monitor = Monitor()
```

**other_module.py**

```
from monitor import monitor
monitor.write("Foo")
```

Comment: That really works. Although I still don't understand why the classmethod solution doesn't work, your solution solves my problem. Thanks!